# How can I get all apps in django?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, model

I have a Django project with many apps and there will be some more,however I use Mongodb as database instead of relation database like mysql. To avoid the conflicts with django models.py,I create a mymodels.py for each app .Now I want to get all app's information like mymodels.py(I want import all the classes in the mymodels.py I defined) but I don't want to use import command since I have no idea how many apps are there.Is there any methods I can do this?Thank you!
Example:I have django project X with N apps,app1,app2,...appN
I have to import all the mymodels by hand like:

```
from app1.mymodels import *
from app2.mymodels import *
...
from appN.mymodels import *
```

Comment: your approach is wrong. What will you do if there are 2 models with same name in different modules?

Comment: @HaiFengZeng I would just use `import app1.mymodels as models1`, `import app2.mymodels as models2`, etc. so that if any models have the same name they won't be shadowed by the latest import.

Comment: @R.Murray I don't have the same name models,and I would not make it happen.

Comment: @HaiFengZeng In which case just use the code in your question. There's no need to start trying to do anything fancy using `exec` statements and for loops, which shouldn't be used at all if possible.